# I am confused which observer should I use for an order placed event in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to use an observer which will triggered when an order will placed on front end by the user. I am little bit confused which observer I should use for this requirement.

```
sales_order_place_after observer
```

or
`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sales_order_place_after`  is fire when  `place()` of order object is called  and in **magento every payment does not call place()** when  order placed.

---

Where

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

Is **only called when customer** has  been redirect to `checout/onepage/success`. Also this event **only called whenever** **order place from frontend** and customer visit `checout/onepage/success`.

MY suggestion, this two event not proper,We should be use **`checkout_submit_all_after`** this event is fire when order place from frontend and backend.

it is fire immediate order place

Comment: then how to show the message on phtml when event is immediately fired ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest 2 events which detailed scope and information:

- **checkout_submit_all_after**: I will be going with this if I just need to get order information.
- **sales_order_place_after**: I will be going with this event if I want to update order information before save something to the order.
- **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**: This event for success controller, This event won't fire if order was placed from admin or via API.

I hope you got right think.